# How to target a datagridview row or cell from DragDrop event?

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));

        MessageBox.Show(e.X + " " + e.Y + " " + dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex.ToString());

        if (dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("!");
        }

    }
```

If I try to drag an item to a datagridview with the above test code, I receive the correct data from the `data.ToString()` ok but i cannot target a row or cell.

The `RowIndex.ToString()` returns "-1", and my if statement returns false so never enters if coded block.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I think we'll need more info.  I can guess at what HitTest is trying to do, but can we see the code?

Comment: which other part of the code will you need?

Comment: I just want it to return the row that the drop ended on, so that I can populate a cell in that row with the string I am dragging from a listview.

Comment: @womp: HitTest is a standard method in .Net whereby a control returns object information based on location, typically from a mouse click or dragdrop as in this example.  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittest.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the coordinates being passed from DragAndDrop are screen space coordinates.
I think you need to cast the points to the client coordinates space.

```
Point dscreen = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
Point dclient = dataGridView1.PointToClient(dscreen );
DataGridView.HitTestInfo hitTest = dataGridView1.HitTest(dclient.X,dclient.Y);
```

then `hitTest.Row` will have the row index

Comment: worked a treat! I will look up what I did with the PointToClient etc thanks

Comment: Still works in VB.net 2022 as well (after conversion). Thanks. And hitTest.Row is hitTest.RowIndex