# Return Cell in DataGridView where DragDrop landed

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I have a Winforms app written in C#.

I can successfully DragDrop values from one DataGridView to another DataGridView on the same form.

However, I'm unsure how to determine which Cell in the receiving DataGridView the DragDrop operation terminates.

I tried the following code -

```
private void dataContactBusiness_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = dataContactBusiness.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    //...other operations continue here    
}
```

But my hit test is always out of bounds i.e returns Row & Column indices of -1.

Comment: see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835329/how-to-target-a-datagridview-row-or-cell-from-dragdrop-event?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it worked

```
Point dscreen = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
Point dclient = dataGridView1.PointToClient(dscreen );
DataGridView.HitTestInfo hitTest = dataGridView1.HitTest(dclient.X,dclient.Y);
```

as per o_weisman comments